# How can I use python installed with macports?

Tags: python, macos, macports

I have installed python using macports (along with some other python packages from macports). The python executable installed with macports is located in `/opt/local/bin/python-2.7`, whereas the one that comes with mac is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` .

How can I switch to the version installed with macports?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `port select` command:

```
$ port select --list python
Available versions for python:
    none
    python25-apple
    python26-apple
    python27 (active)
    python27-apple
    python33
    python34

$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul  5 2014, 20:17:23)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

$ sudo port select --set python python34
Password:
Selecting 'python34' for 'python' succeeded. 'python34' is now active.

$ python
Python 3.4.1 (default, May 21 2014, 21:17:51)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Type this in your terminal:

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:${PATH}"
```